# IntelliJ IDEA does not recognize JAVA source directory

Tags: intellij-idea

Recently I imported the source code of Flink, but IDEA did not recognize the JAVA source directory, resulting in the failure of normal compilation and reading. I found that the generated  .Iml file does not contain the JAVA source directory, I can manually mark the source directory. Flink's module has 188+, manual mark is too difficult, what should I do? Thank you

[Pictures are as follows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5llCw.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to do:

- Close the project `File | Close Project`
- Close the IDE.
- Open the project directory in File Explorer and delete all .iml files and the .idea directory.
- Re-import the project into IntelliJ from [Existing sources](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/import-project-or-module-wizard.html#open-project).

Comment: Thank you very much. I solved the problem through your answer. At the same time, I also found the following solution on the Flink website https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/flinkdev/ide_setup/